# How to get active ribbon tab with Win32++

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-ribbon-framework

I'm a new winapi programmer and I'm using the Win32++ Framework to build a program with a ribbon bar. In the main window (CRibbonDockFrame) the view is supposed to change when the user changes the active tab in the ribbon bar. Like in a CTab control the `OnTCNSelChange(LPNMHDR pNMHDR)` function is called when the tab is changed.

All standard functions for the ribbon bar:

```
virtual STDMETHODIMP Execute(UINT32 cmdID, UI_EXECUTIONVERB verb, const PROPERTYKEY* key, const PROPVARIANT* ppropvarValue, IUISimplePropertySet* pCmdExProp)
virtual STDMETHODIMP UpdateProperty(UINT32 cmdID, __in REFPROPERTYKEY key, __in_opt  const ROPVARIANT* currentValue, __out PROPVARIANT* newValue)
virtual STDMETHODIMP OnViewChanged( UINT32 viewId, __in UI_VIEWTYPE typeId, __in IUnknown* pView, UI_VIEWVERB verb, INT uReasonCode)
```

work fine, but none of them lets me get the active tab via the ids. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Does the document sample [HTMLEditRibbon](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/27ffb0811ca761741502feaefdb591aebf592193/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/WindowsRibbon/HTMLEditRibbon/CPP/Ribbon/ribbonmarkup.xml#L14) work for you?

Comment: All of them work, but none of them can react to a tab change. Or I missed something…. As I said, I’m new to winapi.